# How to put something in my "include path"?

Tags: c++, header, include

I have all my project include files in a specific dir (called `include`, in my project dir). When I include them in a cpp file, I need to

```
#include "include/somefile.h"
```

How can I make it so that I can do

```
#include <somefile.h>
```

?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Check the documentation for your compiler. It might be something like a "-I" flag, but your mileage will vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-I` flag of the compiler. Like:

```
~$ c++ -Wall -Werror -pedantic -I/home/user/include -c source_file.cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

Using double quotes to include looks within the local working directory, while includes wrapped in angle brackets tell the linker/compiler to look in standard locations such as /usr/bin/ (on *nix platforms). You can tell it to look other places with the -I compiler directive (with gcc/g++ at least, IDEs like Visual Studio have their own mechanisms).